# Login With linked workflow permissions issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

As stated here https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition
that `/v1/people/~` endpoint is available for self-serve use. But when I try to fetch basic profile info from https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/~?format=json
I get this response

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /people/~",
    "status": 403
}
```

I have requested access token with following scopes:
r_liteprofile, r_emailaddress, w_member_social

But Still I am getting the above error. I have searched on stackoverflow already and some answers says that I have to ask for API Access at https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program

But I don't want to do any marketing through linkedin I just want simple Sign In workflow.